# jQuery play animation beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I am really hoping it is. I have a site at http://www.sarahnwatson.com. It has several jQuery animations playing when the page loads, I was wondering if I could do them in reverse when the page unloads.

If so, how? This is the code I am trying to make work, but it doesn't at all.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {                
    $list.children().each(function(i, el) { // loop through the LI elements within $list
        $(el).delay(500 * i).animate({'left': '-300px'}, 1000);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Instead I just get a dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only control events that originate from links in your page. With this in mind, you can override the click event of all links in your page.

```
var goToURL = null;

$('a').click(function() {
   var goToURL = $(this).attr("href");
     $(el).delay(500 * i).animate({'left': '-300px'}, 1000, function() {window.location = gotoURL;});
     return false; // or e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want unload.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
})
```

Comment: But the question is: how do I get the page to wait to finish unloading until my animation completes? or can I?

Comment: No, you can't! You can pop up an alert, save cookies, and do all sorts of crazy stuff, but as far as I know you can't stop the browser from loading a new page so you can run animations before it unloads.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `onbeforeunload` like `onbeforeprint` is not in W3C standard DOM events,
From MDN:

> There is no public specification. onbeforeunload was introduced by
>   Microsoft IE 4 and has subsequently been copied by other browsers.

Anyway Microsoft have this event [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can invoke this event by closing the browser. But for some reason this event is not preventing default browser behavior(closing window or tab) in non-IE browsers.

Here is a good article about `unload` event at [webkit docs](http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/)